# What does "radiographic progression" mean in cancer?

Tags: cancer, medicine

I tried looking up the definition of the term "radiographic progression" using Google and medical dictionary, etc., but I couldn't find its meaning anywhere. All research articles that I found just use it, so I assume it is something common.

Please explain to me what "radiographic progression" means. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Radiographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiography)" refers to imaging modalities like x-rays, CT scans, MRI, etc.

"[Progression](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/progression)" in medical terms is referring to progression of disease, where progression means advancing to the next stage, getting worse, etc.

Radiographic progression in the context of cancer would mean that *based on X-rays, CT, MRI, etc*, the cancer has gotten worse in some way. The exact meaning of progression has to be defined on some rating scale and will differ from study to study. Radiographic progression is not the only way to measure disease progression, other measures can also be used like symptoms experienced.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that was the case but I couldn't find the definition of the term anywhere so I was very confused.

Comment: @Paichu Yeah, I was pretty certain but to verify what I did was to find some journal articles using the term and saw how they defined it operationally, especially in contrast with other methods. I also never found a place where someone said "the definition of radiographic progression is _________" but from context it was easy to infer.